# Stronger version of the convergence theorem for finite Markov chains

Tags: convergence-divergence, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I'm trying to find the proof for a claim which seems to be a stronger version of the convergence theorem for finite Markov chains. I would appreciate the help in that regard.

The claim is as follows:

Let $\left\{ x_{t}\right\}$  be a Markov chain over a finite state space $\chi$ with an aperiodic transition matrix P.

for every essential communicating class $C$, define $h_{C}$ as the only harmonic function that satisfies

$h_{C}\left(y\right)=1\iff y\in C$

$h_{C}\left(y\right)=0\iff y\notin C$

Let $\mu_{0}^{x}$ a distribution that satisfies for all $y\in\chi$
$\mu_{0}^{x}\left[y\right]=1\iff y=x$.

Then

$$
\mu_{0}^{x}P^{t}\rightarrow\sum_{C\text{ essential communicating class }}h_{C}\left(x\right)\pi_{C}
$$